# Is there any valid way to compare two linear mixed effects models based on two different datasets?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model

I am a Master's student and currently analyzing 2 datasets with reading times as dependent variables.

For the first dataset, I used a blocked presentation of the linguistic and visual stimuli, while for the second dataset the stimuli were fully pseudo-randomized. The reaction times were modelled on the very same two factors with 2 levels each (match/mismatch) using linear mixed effects models (LMER).

One of my goals is to find out whether there was a difference between the experiment with blocked presentation and the one with fully pseudo-randomized presentation. The resulting models ended up having the same structure:

\begin{equation}
x_1 * x_2 + (1 + x_1 * x_2|participant) + (1|item)
\end{equation}

I know it makes no sense to do a log likelihood comparison on the models even if they have the same structure, since the data comes from two different experiments. Bearing in mind that I have used the same two factors with the same to levels, same stimuli for the experimental manipulation and that the data differs only with respect to how the stimuli was presented to the participants, is there any valid way to compare these two different outcomes?

Comment: Hi Ana, I edited your question a little to make it clearer but I'm confused by the eqauation structure. Could you some more details to better relate the model structure equation to the other information in the question? Thanks!

Comment: Dear Adam, thank you so much for editing it, I am sorry it was unclear. I just tried to reproduce the structure of the lmer model that I used while analyzing the data in R. Unfortunately I am not able to disclose the name of the independent variable, but I will reproduce the lmer function call here: lmer(logRTresidual ~ Factor1*Factor2+ (1+ Factor1*Factor2|participant) + (1|item_id), data = rt_data_spill_devfr, REML = FALSE)